# How do I run expo apps on android studio without ejecting?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I followed expo documentation, but I can't figure out how to run it on an emulator without ejecting. I've heard ejecting is risky and I can't keep making changes to the app if I eject. When I click run, it gives me `Error: Module not specified`, but there is no module from the dropdown list.

Answer (score 0):

You can run your app on android emulator with expo app on this emulator or make `expo build:android` and select apk option. Then just download and install apk on any device. You don't able to run expo app in android studio like native app without ejecting. I recommend you not to use Expo at all and have a look on [fast line](https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/cross-platform/react-native/), pure react native app is more flexible and with fast line has almost the same benefits like expo app. Development without expo is not a big deal.